# how do I colour using vertex paint?

Tags: modeling

I've been looking around for a while now and its so hard to navigate. Anyway, how do I colour in models? I've tried the vertex paint thing but it disappears after I have selected another part.

Comment: What render engine are you using? Cycles or blender internal?

Comment: Vertex color won't be shown in any shading mode except for Vertex Paint or in Solid shading if proper option on the Properties shelf > Mesh Display is turned on. To render it you have to define material using it. The question is not so clear about what exactly do you want to color and what is your desired goal.

Answer (score 1):

Using Blender Render, To see vertex colors in 3d viewport you need to be at least in textured viewport mode...although you can paint in solid mode also.

And to see  vertex colors in render, your material needs to have "vertex color paint" option enabled.

[image]